Silly question about the proof of uniqueness of Hermite matrix?
I'm trying to understand a detail in the proof of the following theorem, from Blyth/Robertson's Basic Linear Algebra:
(Edit: In the sequel, an Hermite matrix is a matrix in reduced row echelon form.)



We are applying induction in the number of columns, I typically expect that for induction proofs, we can proceed for a certain simple case like $n=1$ to $n=2$ to $n=3$ and see what is happening clearly. I'm perhaps a bit confused here: We know that there is only one Hermite matrix $m\times 1$, from this how can we see that all row-equivalent matrices $A,B$ of size $m\times 2$ are equal? I get that when we apply the row operations to "clean" the next column, we get either
$$\begin{bmatrix}
{1}&{a}\\ 
{0}&{0}\\ 
{0}&{0}\\ 
{\vdots}&{\vdots}
\end{bmatrix}\quad \text{or} \quad \begin{bmatrix}
{1}&{0}\\ 
{0}&{1}\\ 
{0}&{0}\\ 
{\vdots}&{\vdots}
\end{bmatrix}$$
For $n=3$, after we "clean" the next column, we get either:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
{1}&{a}&{b}\\ 
{0}&{0}&{0}\\ 
{0}&{0}&{0}\\ 
{\vdots}&{\vdots}&{\vdots}
\end{bmatrix}\quad \text{or} \quad \begin{bmatrix}
{1}&{a}&{0}\\ 
{0}&{0}&{1}\\ 
{0}&{0}&{0}\\ 
{\vdots}&{\vdots}&{\vdots}
\end{bmatrix} \quad \text{or} \quad \begin{bmatrix}
{1}&{0}&{b}\\ 
{0}&{1}&{c}\\ 
{0}&{0}&{0}\\ 
{\vdots}&{\vdots}&{\vdots}
\end{bmatrix}\quad \text{or} \quad \begin{bmatrix}
{1}&{0}&{0}\\ 
{0}&{1}&{0}\\ 
{0}&{0}&{1}\\ 
{\vdots}&{\vdots}&{\vdots}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Is this how we know that they are equal? At each step they can fit in a single one of these classes?

Remind us what a "Hermite matrix" is, please.  And, are you working over a field, or what?

@kimchilover Sorry I added in the text. Over a field.

I think you're misreading the result.  It's not saying that any matrix of a certain size would be reduced to the same matrix.  It's saying that, given a matrix, it's reduced row echelon form is unique.

As a side note, this looks like a terrible book.  The terminology is non-standard, and the proof is poorly written.

@Paul I understand that the matrix will be reduced to a unique row echelon form. Disclaimer: This is not the complete proof of the result, I posted just a small part of it with the doubt I have.
